# Switching from Lock to ReaderWriterLock

Tags: c#, properties, locking

Is it possible to *easily* convert a property in a C# that uses locking in its getter and setter so that it uses a `ReaderWriterLock` instead?

For instance, consider the following property:

```
object numLock = new object();
public int Num
{
   get
   {
      Lock(numLock)
      {
        return num;
      }
   }
   set
   {
      Lock(numLock)
      {
        num = value;
      }
   }
}
```

What is the fastest way to change this to allow multiple readers or a single writer. Note that the code that need to be changed contain hundreds of similar properties. So, I'm looking for a simple solution to convert the locking mechanism in these properties in a fast and reliable way.

Comment: What have you tried?  Clearly you're aware of the proper type, have you not made any attempts to use it?  If so, what problems did you have with those solutions?

Comment: On a side note, such locks are unlikely to be useful, although we couldn't say for sure without more info.  If you have a lot of properties doing this it's an indication to me that you think you're getting more protection than you actually are.

Comment: This kind of locking accomplishes nothing, an int is already atomic.  Just remove it completely.

Comment: @HansPassant Atleast field needs to be volatile isn't it

Comment: In this case `ReaderWriterLock` and even `ReaderWriterLockSlim` are going to be slower than a plain old `lock`.